# How do I pass a windows environment variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble accessing an API. I have set a windows environment variable which stores an API key. When I call the API with my code I get a json parse error---json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 795: unexpected token at 'FORBIDDEN' (JSON::ParserError) --- I am pretty sure the failure is because the environment variable is not being passed.

```
require 'httparty'
class Recipe
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://food2fork.com/api"
  default_params key: ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"]
  default_options.update(verify: false)
  format :json
  def self.for (keyword)
    puts ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"]
    get("/search", key: ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"] , query: {q: keyword})["recipes"]
  end 
end
puts Recipe.for('chocolate')
```

The puts line displays the correct key to the CLI and if I run the API from my browser with the api key I get the proper response. other than setting the environment variable is there anything else that must be done?

Comment: look into the env var: `puts ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"].inspect`

Comment: Thanks!! that revealed that I somehow had a space in front of the api key. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the environment variable:

```
puts ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"].inspect
```

and make sure that contains a valid value.